# How can I use foreach with conditionalSteps in Jenkins Job DSL

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm trying to use the `conditionalSteps` add in with Jenkins Job DSL to conditionally trigger a build step.  I want this step to trigger if any file in a given set exists.  I am able to get this work by explcitly calling out multiple `fileExists` and an `or`.  However I would like to dynamically create this using a foreach.

Here's what I have been playing with on http://job-dsl.herokuapp.com/

```
def files = ["file1", "file2", "file3"]

job('SomeJob') {
    steps {
        conditionalSteps {
            condition {
                /* This works fine:
                or {
                    fileExists("file1.jenkinsTrigger", BaseDir.WORKSPACE)
                }{
                    fileExists("file2.jenkinsTrigger", BaseDir.WORKSPACE)
                }{
                    fileExists("file3.jenkinsTrigger", BaseDir.WORKSPACE)
                }
                */

                //But I want to create the Or clause from the array above
                or {
                    files.each {
                        fileExists("${it}.jenkinsTrigger", BaseDir.WORKSPACE)
                    }
                }
            }
            runner('Unstable')
            steps {
                gradle 'test'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above gets

```
javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.DslScriptException: (script, line 17) No condition specified
```

and I have tried all manner of combinations to get this work without avail... any tips would be much appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `or` DSL method expects an array of closures. So you need to convert the collection of file names to an array of closure.

Example:

```
def files = ["file1", "file2", "file3"]

job('example') {
  steps {
    conditionalSteps {
      condition {
        or(
          (Closure[]) files.collect { fileName ->
            return {
              fileExists("${fileName}.jenkinsTrigger", BaseDir.WORKSPACE)
            }
          }
        )
      }
      runner('Unstable')
      steps {
        gradle 'test'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sweet! Thanks for taking time to answer